# How can I mirror two macbooks

Tags: macbook-pro, raid, storage, disk-utility

I have two macbooks. I want them to be exact copies. They have different CPUs, RAM, but they have the exact same drives.

I work on both of them. I never work on them simultaneously.

Can I setup something that will update what is new on the one, to the other?

I start doing something on macbook1, I want macbook2 to receive it via somekind of wireless connection.

I have an Airport Extreme, I can setup FTPs and whatever. Both macs will have high speed internet almost all the time.

I don't think DropBox is a solution. I have a lot of data and I don't want it on dropbox. CCC doesn't work bothways it has a source and a destination. Probably there is something with rsync, but is there an automated solution? OSX Server?

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a [Mac OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/) and boot from the network, however you will need to have a third Mac, which might be costly unless you have an old one.
You can [purchase the Server](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id714547929?mt=12) from the AppStore for $20. However, booting your Mac from your server requires a moderate internet connection as well as a quick bandwidth (at the place where the server is and your location) in order to work well.
The server offers a service called NetInstall that will allow you to boot from the server. More information how to active it can be obtained in the server documents in Update client software -> Provide NetInstall service).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use DropBox another option could be ChronoSync.  I have not had personal experience with this application, but the reviews I have read sound very promising.  I am not going to go into full detail about this one, but I think it's worth a read. http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html

A feature of ChronoSync which will probably benefit you the most: http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_tips18.html